# ElasticSearch: A way to know which term hit in which field?

Tags: elasticsearch

there are usecases where I really would like to know which term was matched in which field by my search. With this information I would like to disclose the information which field caused the hit to the user on my webpage. I also would like to know the term playing part in the hit. In my case it is a database identifier, so I would take the matched term - an ID - get the respective database record and display useful information to the user.
I currently know two ways: Highlighting and the explain API. However, the first requires stored values which seems unnecessary. The second is meant for debugging only and is rather expensive so I wouldn't want it to run with every query.
I don't know another way which is confusing: The highlighting algorithms need the information I want to use anyway, can't I just get it somehow?

On a related note, I would also be interested in the opposite case: Which term did not hit at all? This information would allow for features like "terms that didn't match your query" like Google does sometimes (where the respective words are shown in grey-strikeout).

Thanks for hints!